# Wildcard SSL and subdomains

Tags: ssl

I have an issue that I'm facing. I have a site with a wildcard SSL cert and am trying to create a subdomain in Cpanel which lies outside of the public_html documents root.

When I type the subdomain (subdomain.mainsite.com) into my web browser, I can access the subdomain location correctly, however when I prepend the HTTPS://, I am redirected to the main site.

Is this normal behaviour? How do I go about setting up this subdomain outside the document root and securing it via SSL?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you host the sub-domain as add-on domains?
   Please make sue to create physical directory for each sub-domain
2. If sub-domain is configured on separate file directory, you should review .htaccess file and redirection rules.